# RDP Dual Monitors treated as one

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

The Windows Remote Desktop Connection tool allows use of dual monitors by leveraging the /span option.  The problem with that option is that it treates the remote dual monitors as one large desktop instead of two distinct desktops for each of the left and right monitors.  This is a pain because maximizing a Window or application will span both monitors and consume the entire screen unless manually stretching it into position of one monitor.  Another problem is that dialog boxes that are suppose to pop up in the middle of the desktop now are split dead-evenly in half by the two monitors.  Is there another option that I could be using so taht the remote monitors map exactly to my monitors instead of one giant spanned desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `/multimon` option instead of `/span`, but it's only supported by newer versions of Windows. I'm not sure which versions exactly; I'll leave that to you to research.

Comment: The feature is available since Windows 7, originally only in the Enterprise and Ultimate edition. Later the option was added to the GUI connection dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) or [Splitview](http://www.splitview.com/Terminal-Server-Edition) on the RDP server which will give the users the option controlling windows using controls and presets.